# Select Angular Material display state ( checked or not ) multi items dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `<mat-select>` for angular material with multiple choice, is there property to set for `<mat-option>` to check or not an option depending on a param.
For Example if I have 3 objects:

```
 users =  [{ name: 'name1', checked: true}, {name: 'name2', checked: false}, {name: 'object3', checked: true}]
```

I want to get this when my select is displayed:

[image]

```
<mat-select placeholder="users" multiple [(ngModel)]="bookform.users" name="data_scientists">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let user of users" class="mat-selected" [value]="user.id">
     <img src="http://corktrainingcentre.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/person.png" class="member-picture">{{user.name}} 
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: i want the checkbox to be checked or not depending on a params. not to be all unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do is not exactly supported natively, but you can achieve it with something like this:

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4kkgk)

Comment: Thanks for the help